# DJI Manifold 2 (running on nvidia jetson tx2) USB devices cannot work after updating with Ubuntu's software update

Tags: embedded, nvidia, dji-sdk, nvidia-jetson

After installing jetpack 4.4 on the DJI manifold 2G (Nvidia jetson tx2 version), the internal Ubuntu software updater pings me for a 2.3GB sized update.

Following which, after completing the update, all USB ports are non-responsive, and the processor's fan will continuously run at full speed. Restarting the device does not improve nor make things worst. The only way out seemed to be re-flashing the firmware with jetpack 4.4.

The specs are, if they are helpful:
Processor: ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l) × 4
Graphics: NVIDIA Tegra X2 (nvgpu)/integrated
Os type: 64-bit
Memory: 8gb

Any help, or similar experiences and work-arounds are greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Edit
-Attempting to use the Manifold 2G image provided by DJI returned this error when executing sudo tar -zxvf

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

As such, i am unable to downgrade back to the Jetpack 3.3 version

Answer (score 1):

DJI mf2G uses a specifically modified version of the jetpack with DJI-preset serial port config.

Publicly, there is one standard version on the DJI website that you can restore to factory default.  https://www.dji.com/sg/manifold-2/downloads

Privately, the DJI dev group also give out a Jetpack 4.3 version DJI image that can allow you to use docker(factory default does not allow). But I can not share it publicly. You may ask DJI support to release this version to you.

Comment: I have actually tried to use their mf2g firmware to restore. But there is a problem with their file. I encountered an unexpected EOF error. Is there someone specific in DJI support one should speak to ?

Comment: it sounds like you have a hardware error. Try to contact dev@dji.com.  I flashed a lot of mf2G already. havn`t had your error

Comment: Are you able to also perform sudo apt-get upgrade and/or software updates ? If i perform software update the USB ports will fail to work. Have you faced similar problems ?

Comment: I dont do any upgrades.  Disable upgrade will make your system live longer. If you really need to upgrade. use a fixed image. You can download v3.3 from dji official website.  I`m uploading v4.4 . will update the image link here

Comment: Hi manifold2G_image_V0.4.4.0.tar  is available here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jj6RJ02BkJku6FD-K86I7ECvZ2arQp2z/view?usp=sharing  if you really have to upgrade. use this

Comment: Thank you for sharing ! Will reply here if i encounter any issue after trying it. I will also post another question about the v3.3 one. I have downloaded from their website but there are errors. Hopefully their staff sees it.

Comment: hello I have tried it. I encountered the same errors of
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive. I tried it on both my MF2G and MF2C using the same sudo tar commands

Comment: Emm strange. Is it that your PC had some issue? by right both image can work in my PC. Possible to switch to another PC and try?

Comment: I tried on another pc as well. Even tried transferring with a thumb drive. Regarding the earlier v0.3.3 version, somehow using wget to download it helped to solve the EOF problem.

Comment: OK. seems you have a downloaded filed incomplete problem. First time to hear this

Comment: yup... thank you for the help anyway ! Will try upgrade again in the future